# Form is not responsive to window resizing

Tags: html, css, forms, input, styling

I am recreating a apple login page. One problem though, the form inputs are not responsive. When resizing the window, the background changes to fit the window but the login form does not. Here is my code, both html, and css.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.login {
    position: absolute; /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
    width: 1140px;
    top: 30%;
    left: 500;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 23pt;
}

#space-password {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

html {
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

input{
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

and here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lan="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400"     rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <form class="login">
                <p>Apple ID:</p><br>
                <input type="text" name="Apple ID"><br>
                <p id="space-password">Password:</p><br>
                <input type="password" name="Password">
            </form>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit: All your guys solutions are working just now the input boxes width fills the whole screen! Anyway to stop this?

Comment: use max-width :100% in input{max-width :100%}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.login {
width:50%;
 margin:0 auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 23pt;
}
.login p{ text-align:left}
#space-password {
padding-top: 20px;
}

html {
  color: whitesmoke;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

input{
border-radius: 50px;
color: aliceblue;
background-color: #34495e;
width:80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html lan="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400"     rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form class="login">
            <p>Apple ID:</p><br>
            <input type="text" name="Apple ID"><br>
            <p id="space-password">Password:</p><br>
            <input type="password" name="Password">
        </form>

    </header>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't make the width a 100% else the input boxes fill the whole screen.

Comment: It is depend on the width of the parent of input boxes.  If you dont want to fill the whole screen then declare a width on your form. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace this css

      * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.login {
 position: absolute; /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
width: auto;
top: 30%;
left: 0;
right:0;
 margin:0 auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 23pt;
}
.login p{ text-align:left}
#space-password {
padding-top: 20px;
}

html {
  color: whitesmoke;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

input{
border-radius: 50px;
color: aliceblue;
background-color: #34495e;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This makes the input boxes fill the whole width of the screen.

Comment: input{width: auto;}

Answer (score 0):

change `width: 1140px;` to `width: 100%` or width:80%(ur wish).. Basically for responsive Set all parameter values in %(percentage).

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100vh;
}

.login {
 position: absolute; /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
width: auto;
top:10%;
left: 10%;
right:0;
 margin:0 auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 23pt;
}
.login p{ text-align:left}
#space-password {
padding-top: 20px;
}

html {
  color: whitesmoke;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 
}

input{
border-radius: 50px;
color: aliceblue;
background-color: #34495e;
width:80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html lan="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400"     rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form class="login">
            <p>Apple ID:</p><br>
            <input type="text" name="Apple ID"><br>
            <p id="space-password">Password:</p><br>
            <input type="password" name="Password">
        </form>

    </header>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked but now the  text input boxes are filling the whole width of the screen. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Set `width: 50% ` or less

Answer (score 0):

You should use `width: 80%` with the properties `min-width: ZZZpx` and `max-width: YYYpx`. This will make your form the 80% of your body, but if a little screen make the form smaller than `ZZZpx`, form width will be constant (`ZZZpx`). Also, if a big screen make the form greater than `YYYpx`, the form width will be constant (`YYYpx`). The `margin/padding: 0 auto` is to center horizontally.

To calculate ZZZ and YYY, you should test some screen sizes, to see what must be the min. and max. value.

Lastly, I advice you to change your `html {}` in css, to `body {}`; adding `max-width` and `min-width` properties.

This could be your code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.login {
    /* Quit also this */
    /*
    position: absolute;
    top:10%;
    left: 10%;
    right:0;        
    width: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: auto;
    */
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    font-size: 23pt;
}

.login p{ 
    text-align:left
}

#space-password {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 

    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 1220px;
    max-width: 1600px;
}

input{
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: aliceblue;
    background-color: #34495e;

    width:80%;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html lan="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400"     rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Welcome-Sign in</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <form class="login">
            <p>Apple ID:</p><br>
            <input type="text" name="Apple ID"><br>
            <p id="space-password">Password:</p><br>
            <input type="password" name="Password">
        </form>

    </header>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **max-width** in your **.login** class of css property. And **width** should be **100%**.

**jsfiddle.net/raeeshalam/ao7j0us5/**

Comment: Check this url **https://jsfiddle.net/raeeshalam/ao7j0us5/** . I hope this snippet help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet help you for better understanding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.login {
  position: absolute; /* Turns the the text box to absolute from static (allows free control of placement) */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
#space-password {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
html {
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(hero.jpeg); 
}

input{
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  background-color: #34495e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <form class="login">
    <p>Apple ID:</p>
    <input type="text" name="Apple ID">

    <p id="space-password">Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="Password">
  </form>
</header>
```